# How did a new Inka recover from being cut off from his inheritance?

Tags: economy, royal-succession, inca, precolumbian-era

When a reigning Inka ("Inka" is the quechua spelling, matter of preference) died, [his successor was disinherited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapa_Inca#Functions) and all properties, servants and lands were split among the Inka's other offspring. The Inka was expected to be a great warrior and this tradition was meant to incentivize constant conquest and expansion.

My question is, how did the successor recover from such a setback? If I'm reading this correctly, he was denied income from lands and his subjects now served his siblings or the Qoya, the late Inka's wife.

Comment: Presumably if the policy was intended to incentive conquest, the survivor assembled a force and set out for conquest.